# The topology generated by open intervals of rational numbers

Tags: general-topology, rational-numbers, real-numbers

Let
$B = \{ \mathbb{R} \} \cup \{ (a,b) \cap\mathbb {Q} \ ,\  a\lt b \ ,\   a,b \in\mathbb{Q}\}$

Thus, a set $V \in B$ if it is either equal to $\mathbb{R}$ or if it is in the intersection of $\mathbb{Q}$ with an open interval with rational endpoints.

a) Show that $B$ forms a base for a topology $T$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

b) Show that this topology does not contain nor be contained in the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$.

c) Is $(\mathbb{R}, T)$ compact? Is it separable? Is it connected?

I think  have solved a)

All irrational numbers are contained in the set $\mathbb{R}$ and all the other numbers are contained in some intersection of an open set with $\mathbb{Q}$. So each point $x$, is contained in some set $v \in B$. Also if a point $x$ belongs to the intersection of two base sets then I can find some set containing $x$ that is contained in that intersection.

Comment: Note that in this topology, $\mathbb{R}$ is the *only* open subset which contains irrational numbers. This can solve at least most of the above questions, if not all of them.

Comment: so.. compact: nope, no finite sub cover for R. connected: yes. For b) i can see it has less open sets than the usual topology but i dont know how to show its not contained in it.

Comment: @budhha, its explained in the text, i just see Q as Q..?.

Comment: The space is compact. The only open set containing, say, $\pi$ is $\mathbb{R}$ and so any open cover in this topology must have $\mathbb{R}$ in the cover, and so it has a finite subcover, namely $\{\mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: hmm ok, i thought since the reals are not compact as a space it would extend to this situation.

Comment: for part b, show that the Id map is not continuous or open.  is the preimage of (a,b) in B open ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_topologies

Comment: Your space is connected - every open set in your space is $\Bbb{R}$ or at most countable. On the other hand, every closed set in your space is $\varnothing$ or uncountable so there is no nontrivial clopen set.

Comment: Alright, thanks buddha and tetori. For separable: Q is contained as a subset of the space, which is dense in R and countable. So (R,T) is separable. correct?

Comment: @estamp Density is a topological property. So you cannot use density in the usual topology to infer density in this topology (though insofar as it is defined via inequalities, there's a vague relationship). You'd have to justify density in the specific topology.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand. I can generate Q by taking unions of base sets, and its closure is the entire space R.

Comment: Regarding your comment [“ i thought since the reals are not compact as a space it would extend to this situation”](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/908107/the-topology-generated-by-open-intervals-of-rational-numbers#comment1873747_908107). Compactness is a property of the *topology* of a space.  The reals *with the usual topology* are not compact. But with a different topology, they are compact. For example, the reals with the [indiscrete topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiscrete_topology) *are* a compact space. The choice of topology changes the properties of the space.

Comment: A necessary and sufficient condition that a family $B$ of subsets of a set $S$ is a base for a topology on $S$ is: (1). $\cup B=S.$ (I.e. each $s\in S$ belongs to at least one member of $B$), and (2) if $b_1 ,b_2\in B$ and $s\in b_1\cap b_2$ then there exists $b_3\in B$ such that $s\in b_3\subset b_1\cap b_2.$.... And note that if $b_1\cap b_2\in B\cup \{\emptyset\}$ for all $b_1,b_2\in B$ then condition (2) is satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B = \mathcal{I} \cup \mathcal{J}$ where $\mathcal{I} = \left\{ \mathbb{R} \right\}$, $\mathcal{J} = \left\{ (a,b) \cap \mathbb{Q} | a<b, a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \right\}$. Suppose that $U,V \in B$. If $U,V \in \mathcal{I}$, then clearly $U \cap V \in \mathcal{I}$. If one of $U,V$ is in $\mathcal{I}$ whereas the other is in $\mathcal{J}$, then clearly $U \cap V \in \mathcal{J}$. If both $U$ and $V$ are in $\mathcal{J}$, then $U \cap V \in \mathcal{J}$ from the basic properties of open intervals. Hence $B$ forms a basis.

Let $\mathcal{T}_B$ be the topology generated by $B$ and $\mathcal{T}$ be the usual topology. Since the interval $(0,1) \in \mathcal{T}$ contains irrational numbers $(0,1) \not \in \mathcal{T}_B$. Therefore $\mathcal{T}_B$ does not contains $\mathcal{T}$. Since the interval $(0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q} \in \mathcal{T}_B$ is not open in the usual topology, we have $\mathcal{T}$ does not contains $\mathcal{T}_B$.

The space $X = (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T}_B)$ is compact. To see this let $\mathcal{O}$ be an open cover of $X$. Since $\sqrt{2} \in U \in \mathcal{O}$ implies $U = \mathbb{R}$, we have a finite subcover $I \subseteq \mathcal{O}$.

The space $X$ is separable. To see this, consider $D = \left\{ 0 \right\}$. For every irrational $r$, there is unique neighborhood $\mathbb{R}$ showing that the closure of $D$ is just $X$. Hence $X$ is separable.

The space $X$ is connected. To see this, suppose that $U$ and $V$ are proper non empty open subsets of $X$. Then they cannot cover $X$ simply because they do not have any irrational numbers.